# how to remove a complete layout in custom list view adapter in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application i want to remove the row in custom list item whenever i touch the list view item layout. i try to delete with the help of position. but it is stopped.

code:

```
  @Override


  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Typeface custom_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),
                "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recharge_listitem, null);

        TextView   orderitemid_delete=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderitemid);
        TextView accountnumber = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.accountnumber);
        TextView servicename = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.servicetypname);
        TextView planamount = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.rechargeamount);
        final ImageView close = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.crosse_close_img);
        accountnumber.setTypeface(custom_regular);
        servicename.setTypeface(custom_regular);
        planamount.setTypeface(custom_regular);
        //orderitemid = bpData.get(position).getOrderitemID();
        // Log.v("TAG_orderitemid",""+orderitemid);
        orderid = bpData.get(position).getOrderid();

        final LinearLayout layoutrecharge = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rechargelay);
        layoutrecharge.setTag(position);


        accountnumber.setText(bpData.get(position).getAccountNumber());
        servicename.setText(bpData.get(position).getServicename());
        planamount.setText("Rs." + bpData.get(position).getRechargeamount());
        orderitemid_delete.setText(bpData.get(position).getOrderitemID());


        totalamount.setText("Rs " + bpData.get(position).getAmount());
        layoutrecharge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                new GetdeleteOrderItem().execute(WebUrl.RechargeServiceURL + "deleteOrderItem");
                //int deletePos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

                TextView orderitemid_delete = (TextView)layoutrecharge
                        .findViewById(R.id.orderitemid);
                orderitemidfordelete = orderitemid_delete.getText().toString();
                int deletePos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                bpData.remove(deletePos);




                Helper.getListViewSize(recharge_lv);//run it
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                reloadcas_cb.setChecked(false);

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

error:

    02-26 18:06:55.933  29715-29715/com.reloadapp.reload E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 0
                at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
                at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:399)
                at com.reloadapp.reload.fragments.Payment_Actiivity$PaymentAdapter$1.onClick(Payment_Actiivity.java:488)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3571)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14247)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In my application i want to remove the row in custom list item whenever i touch the list view item layout. i try to delete with the help of position. but it is stopped.

Comment: please give us more info about your list, is it load data from the web, sqliteDB...?

Comment: @keerthij: `but it is stopped.` please add log with question

Comment: Pl take reference from here.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586910/selecting-item-from-listview-and-delete-it-onclick-android-to-do-list-applicat

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K... i done whatever  you told to me before. now iit is stopeed. when using layout

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 0 

Adapter has no data bind so, you can't delete item before binding any data

Comment: at that time that is button. now this is layout

Comment: can you put whole adapter code here.. ?

Comment: please see my edited post  @Android Weblineindia

Comment: please help me @ ρяσѕρєя K ji

Comment: Please Quick Check below things 
- getCount() in adapter must have bpData.size() if you are not passing data in super class
- before calculating list size try to notify list adapter first after removing data

Comment: do you have onResume()  on your class?, are you using a DBHelper?

Answer (score 0):

please first put your actions inside asyncTask onPostExecuted and try to do something like this:

```
yourAdaptersList.remove(positionToRemove);
yourAdapter = new Adapter(yourAdaptersList);
yourListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```